# check if a value exists in dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have something like, (which works fine and) gives me key and variables of values.

```
for k,v in x.iteritems():
        print k, v.samplekey,v.units,v.comment
```

where x is dictionary and v is netCDF4 [variable](http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/#section4). For dictionary 'v', there may or maynot exist a value for the keys. [e.g. key 'units' may exist in one of the items in dictionary while might be missing from others.]

I am getting `AttributeError: Attribute not found`. message when the key is not found in dictionary. I am trying to fill in `N/A` whenever no key isn't found.

Comment: You cannot access to your dictionary values using don notation. You can use *Indexing* or `dict.get()` attribute in order to get a value. And in this case you can use `get()` which gets a default value to return in key missing time.

Comment: Please see the edited question.

Comment: I'd really like to know why this is getting so many downvotes, Please leave a comment if you are down-voting, too :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `hasattr` method:

```
def attr(x, a):
    return x.__getattribute__(a) if hasattr(x, a) else None

print k, attr(v, 'samplekey'), attr(v, 'units'), attr(v, 'comment')
```

Or alternatively, the `getattr` builtin (thanks RemcoGerlich!):

```
print k, getattr(v, 'samplekey', None)
```

Comment: Question edited for clarity. v.get won't work because v is a netCDF4 variable

Comment: you could use a function for that: `def attr(x, a): return x.__getattribute__(a) if hasattr(x, a) else None` and then `print k, attr(v, 'samplekey')`. Yes, that code is still ugly, but I don't know how to do better :p - edited answer

Comment: Your attr() is basically the builtin getattr().

Comment: @RemcoGerlich thanks, i had forgotten this function! I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use `getattr`, which takes a default for when the attribute doesn't exist:

```
for k,v in x.iteritems():
    print (k,
           getattr(v, 'samplekey', 'N/A'),
           getattr(v, 'units', 'N/A'),
           getattr(v, 'comment', 'N/A'))
```